# Android: not able to add listview items dynamically through volley

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

Hi I'm working on `CardSwipe` functionality like tinder. (For understanding see the attached image)

[image]

For this i followed [this code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx4wif47mj1pp7x/CardSwipe.rar), when using static data like bellow, I'm successfully adding items in `ListView`

```
private void loadCards2(){

        itemsaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            CardSwipeItems items = new CardSwipeItems();

            items.setCardImageUrl("http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PnxsTxV8y3g/maxresdefault.jpg");
            items.setCardDescription("But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.");

            itemsaArrayList.add(items);
        }

        flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        myAppAdapter = new CardSwipeAdapter(itemsaArrayList, CardSwipeActivity.this);
        flingContainer.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);

        initControlls();

    }
```

But when I'm trying to add the items dynamically by using volley means, items are not adding in the `ListView`. (For this volley 
please see the `loadCards()` method in the `CardSwipeActivity`)

I tried lot of approaches to load the items in the list view dynamically. For ex: I used `Thread` (For code see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lglhtzbrvr6fixq/CardSwipeActivity%20%28With%20thread%29.java)) and i also used `Handler` (For code see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe6jjzvn7qgl0ku/CardSwipeActivity%20%28With%20handler%29.java)) but I'm not able to add the items in `ListView` dynamically

If any one know the solution for this means please tell me. Thank you.......

**Edit**

```
*My method*

private void loadCards(){

        String Url = "myApi";
        Log.e("Url", Url);

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CardSwipeActivity.this, null, null);
        ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(CardSwipeActivity.this, null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
        spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#009689"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(spinner);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                dialog.dismiss();

                if(response != null && !response.startsWith("<HTML>")){

                    Log.e("OnResponse", response);

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        if(jsonArray.length() > 0){

                            itemsaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject singleObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String imgId = singleObj.getString("avatar_file_id");
                                String name = singleObj.getString("name");

                                CardSwipeItems items = new CardSwipeItems();

                                Log.e("imgId", imgId);
                                Log.e("name", name);

                                items.setCardImageUrl(imgId);
                                items.setCardDescription(name);

                                itemsaArrayList.add(items);

                            }

                            flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
                            myAppAdapter = new CardSwipeAdapter(itemsaArrayList, CardSwipeActivity.this);
                            flingContainer.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);

                            initControlls();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }else{

                    Log.e("Internet", "Internet");
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                if(error != null){

                    Log.e("error", error.toString());
                }else{


                }
            }
        }){

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token","b32daf7b50c7f21dba80dd0651174e3839c22f56");
                params.put("user_id","386");

                Log.e("Headers", "**********Headers*************");
                Log.e("token","b32daf7b50c7f21dba80dd0651174e3839c22f56");
                Log.e("user_id","386");

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CardSwipeActivity.this);
        queue.add(request);
        queue.getCache().remove(Url);

    }
```

Comment: paste problematic code here. We shouldn't have to download your project

Comment: have you tried runOnUiThread method instated on simple Runnable class.

Comment: @VladMatvienko: Please see my edit

Comment: @Ankur1994a: Ya i also tried that one but it's not working for code see this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/lglhtzbrvr6fixq/CardSwipeActivity%20%28With%20thread%29.java

Comment: Are getting data in reposne? and did u debug the code to check if there is exception or data not fetched and all?

Comment: @Vickyexpert: Ya i'm getting response, and i debugged everything

Comment: check my ans if it is work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items dynamically to the adapter by addding items to the list you passed originally to adapter like this:

```
itemsaArrayList.add(items);
```

than you need to notify the adapter like this from your UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

And to call it on the UI-Thread, use have to use runOnUiThread() of Activity. Then only, notifyDataSetChanged() will work.

Also have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting response from server then try to move below line from onResponse method to onCreate method.

```
     flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
```

Hope this will work